# Xpath query in this situation --grouping values?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

If I have this XML:

```
<Events>
    <Properties>
      <Property Descriptor="100">1377349460.298</Property>
      <Property Descriptor="101">1</Property>
      <Property Descriptor="24000">C1234Test1</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
      <Property Descriptor="100">1377349462.298</Property>
      <Property Descriptor="101">1</Property>
      <Property Descriptor="24000">C4321Test2</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
      <Property Descriptor="100">1377349462.300</Property>
      <Property Descriptor="101">1</Property>
      <Property Descriptor="24000">C1234Test1</Property>
    </Properties>
</Events>
```

How can I select only `Descriptor="100"` for the FIRST occurrence of each `Descriptor="24000"` considering only the first 5 characters of this property? For example, selecting only 1377349460.298 [for C1234] and 1377349462.298 [for C4321]?

Xpath 2.0

I have no idea how to try it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some remarks: Your XML is not well-formed (only single root element allowed). Also, sure you only want the first four characters? The input lets me guess you might want five (my answer is for four characters anyway, but that's easy to change). And, it might be reasonable to present IDs in here that actually differ in their last few character positions, to function as a test for correct answers.

Comment: 1 - Absolutely correct: It's 5 characters. 2 - Edited with "Test2" instead of "Test1" for C4321 3 - Added higher level node.

Answer (score 2):

Find all matching identifiers, then for each of them, find the first result.

```
for $id in distinct-values(//Property[@Descriptor=24000]/substring(., 1, 4))
return
  //Properties[Property[@Descriptor=24000 and starts-with(., $id)]][1]
      /Property[@Descriptor=100]
```